# How to test to get all value of StateFlow in Coroutine?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

Test Result is always received first value(=init) and last value(=success)
How to get LoaderType State (Fail Case)

Without the `delay()` function, the test case consistently fails, and only the initial state and success state are obtained. How can the test case be successful without the `delay()`?

```kotlin
fun getExhibitions(loaderType: LoaderType) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        state.update { it.loading(loaderType) } // #1 Change State (to Loading)

        val result = useCase.getExhibitions(
            params = GetExhibitionsUseCase.Params(shopId, sellerId)
        )

        when (result) {
            is UseCaseResult.Success -> {
                val displayModel = mapper.mapExhibitionList(result.value)
                state.update { it.loadingSuccess(displayModel.exhibitions) } // #2 Change State (to Success)
            }
            is UseCaseResult.Fail -> {
                onErrorGetExhibitions(result.throwable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Test
fun load_success() = runTest {

    // given
    prepareViewModel_success()

    viewModel.uiState.test {

        // init
        assert((awaitItem() as UiState.Loading).loaderType == QCommerceLoaderType.NONE)

        // when
        viewModel.getExhibitions(loaderTyp = LoaderType.TEXT)

        // then
        assert((awaitItem() as UiState.Loading).loaderType == QCommerceLoaderType.TEXT) // Fail Case
        assert((awaitItem() as UiState.Success).exhibitions.isNotEmpty())
    }

}
```

Below cases are Passes

```kotlin
fun getExhibitions(loaderType: LoaderType) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        state.update { it.loading(loaderType) } // #1 Change State (to Loading)

        delay(500) // Add this code

        val result = useCase.getExhibitions(
            params = GetExhibitionsUseCase.Params(shopId, sellerId)
        )

        when (result) {
            is UseCaseResult.Success -> {
                val displayModel = mapper.mapExhibitionList(result.value)
                state.update { it.loadingSuccess(displayModel.exhibitions) } // #2 Change State (to Success)
            }
            is UseCaseResult.Fail -> {
                onErrorGetExhibitions(result.throwable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun getExhibitions(loaderType: LoaderType) {
    state.update { it.loading(loaderType) } // Edit Location
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = useCase.getExhibitions(
            params = GetExhibitionsUseCase.Params(shopId, sellerId)
        )

        when (result) {
            is UseCaseResult.Success -> {
                val displayModel = mapper.mapExhibitionList(result.value)
                state.update { it.loadingSuccess(displayModel.exhibitions) } // #2 Change State (to Success)
            }
            is UseCaseResult.Fail -> {
                onErrorGetExhibitions(result.throwable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```